Do the Vyuha forms of Vishnu perform leelas and great deeds like the avataric forms?
The avataric forms Rama, Krishna, Varaha et al are well known for their leelas and great deeds like killing Ravana.
But Vishnu is also said to have Vyuha forms Vasudeva, Sankarshana, Pradyumna, and Aniruddha described in the Pancharatra Agamas.
(1) are the Vyuha forms Sankarshana and Vasudeva the same as the avataric forms Balarama and Krishna?
(2) Do the Vyuha forms have leelas and/or deeds connected with them?
